# Rails: How to include zeros in a group count query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, group

I'd like to include zeros in a count.

Here is my query for my count:

```
@hammer_counts = current_user.tools.where(shed_id: @sheds.pluck(:id)).joins(:hammer, :user).group(['hammers.name', 'users.first_name']).count
```

This gives me the following output:

```
{["Hammer 1", "John"]=>5, ["Hammer 1", "Lisa"]=>1, ["Hammer 3", "John"]=> 1, ["Hammer 4", "John"]=> 1}
```

Here is what i'd like to achieve if possible with zeros included.

```
{["Hammer 1", "John"]=>5, ["Hammer 1", "Lisa"]=>1, ["Hammer 3", "John"]=>1, ["Hammer 3", "Lisa"]=>0, ["Hammer 4", "John"]=> 1, ["Hammer 4", "Lisa"]=>0}
```

ty

Comment: Do a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example? I'm not familiar with left join at all and everything I try based on examples of a left join gives the same result without zeros. Thanks.

Comment: Thats ORM, right? I'm not sure how to do left join in that format.

Comment: Maybe the docs have the info on left join https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins .